# Command Prompt won't run external commands

Tags: cmd, command, external

My command prompt won't run exe files without their extensions.

For example, help won't work, but help.exe works fine. Does anyone know what the culprit might be?

Comment: what does `assoc .exe` and `ftype exefile` say?

Comment: assoc .exe says .exe=exefile and ftype exefile says exefile="%1" %*

Comment: Hm - that's ok. Sorry, no more ideas from me.

Comment: The search for executable files depends on the `PATHEXT` environment variable and it should include `.EXE` in its list of recognized extensions. Open a command window and type `set pathexp` to see the value of the variable.

Comment: Seems like my user account's PATHEXT variable didn't include .EXE! I just deleted it so it reverted to the global PATHEXT variable and that fixed it! Thank you!